# Tricky object flattening

Tags: javascript, object, flatten

I'm really don't want to reinvent the bicycle, so maybe somebody already been in situation when you have an Object like this:

```js
{
   a: {
      site1: {
         type1: {
            item1: 42,
            item2: 13
         }
      },
      site2: {
         type2: {
            item3: 35
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And you need to get it into an Array:

```js
[
   [ a, site1, type1, 42],
   [ a, site1, type1, 13],
   [ a, site2, type2, 35]
]
```

Comment: Do you not need the 42, 13 etc...? Or do you mean you want the values in the final array (instead of the keys)?

Comment: That's a recursive tree traversal.

Comment: @BrettGregson, you are right, I need number instead `itemN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to recurse through the tree:

```
const data = {
  a: {
    site1: {
      type1: {
        item1: 42,
        item2: 13,
      },
    },
    site2: {
      type2: {
        item3: 35,
      },
    },
  },
};

function walk(data, out, path = []) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const newPath = [...path, key];
    const value = data[key];
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      walk(value, out, newPath);
    } else {
      out.push([newPath, value]);
      // Or if you really don't need the value...
      //out.push(newPath);
    }
  });
}

const out = [];
walk(data, out);
console.log(out);
```

outputs

```
[
  [ [ 'a', 'site1', 'type1', 'item1' ], 42 ],
  [ [ 'a', 'site1', 'type1', 'item2' ], 13 ],
  [ [ 'a', 'site2', 'type2', 'item3' ], 35 ]
]
```

By changing that one commented-out line you can get your original desired outcome, without the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit simpler solution:

```js
function flattenObject(objToFlat, path = []) {
  return Object.keys(objToFlat).reduce(
    (result, key) => [
      ...result,
      ...(typeof objToFlat[key] === 'object'
        ? flattenObject(objToFlat[key], [...path, key])
        : [[...path, objToFlat[key]]]),
    ],
    []
  );
}
```

Note that you don't need to pass empty array to function.

You can test solution in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IM5v3fyAMrfV5HKS?open=lib%2Fscript.js